# ClearCase to Git migration. Steps to migrate from ClearCase to Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, clearcase

I am working on ClearCase to Git migration. Anybody having commands or steps to migrate from ClearCase to Git. ClearCase & Git installed on Linux environment.

actually, we have to migrate from ClearCase to Bitbucket. I came to know , Clearcase to GIT then GIT to bitbucket

Comment: Once you have it in git, you can just push the branches into github, that's not something special you need to find out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket is a Git repository hosting service, so you don't have to do anything special except create a new empty repository on that service, and push your local Git repository (using the credentials of the Bitbucket account used to create the repository)

As for ClearCase to Git import, from [my past experience](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A6309%20%5Bclearcase%5D%20git%20migration), I would:

- *not* import the full history, only major labels or UCM baselines
- split Vobs per project, each project being one Git repository
- revisit what was versioned in Vobs: some large files/binaries might need to be `.gitignore`'d in the new Git repository.

So:

- create a snapshot view (or snapshot UCM view if your are using UCM) of what you want to import (a past baseline, or `LATEST main`, or ...)
- create a new Git repository and cd in it
- do a `git --work-tree=/path/to/ClearCase/view add .` to import files
- `git commit -m "import of (past baseline, or latest, or ...)`"

Repeat the add/commit to import incrementally all your past baselines (if you want to keep a small history).
Or just import the LATEST, and keep the ClearCase repository around, in read-only mode, if you need to explore past history.